# How to get Gemfire data into Resultset and iterate in java?

Tags: java, resultset, gemfire

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM /items";
ClientCache cache = new ClientCacheFactory().create();
QueryService queryService = cache.getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);

SelectResults results = (SelectResults)query.execute();
```

I want to get the results data into resultset like rdbms.  Is there any way to get the data in resultset and iterate using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you really need to go through the [GemFire User Guide](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/gemfire/about_gemfire.html) if you want to get proficient on its usage and understand how things work. Regarding this particular question, please have a look at the [Querying](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/developing/querying_basics/chapter_overview.html) chapter, it contains useful examples and explanations.

In short, you can iterate through `SelectResults` doing something like the following:

```
SelectResults<YourEntity> results = (SelectResults<YourEntity>) query.execute();
for (Iterator<YourEntity> iterator = results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    YourEntity entity = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(entity);
}
```

The code above assumes, among other things, that the region `items` is populated with instances of the class `YourEntity` and that the class itself is deployed to the server's class path.
Cheers.

Comment: can you look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52543902/10362943 @Juan Ramos