# Invalid Http Response for Gemfire?

Tags: java, http, gemfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBgiT.png)    public class GemfireTest extends SecurityManager {

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws NameResolutionException, TypeMismatchException, QueryInvocationTargetException, FunctionDomainException, IOException {

                System.setProperty("gemfire.locators", "localhost[8091]");
                Properties properties = new Properties();

             ServerLauncher serverLauncher = new ServerLauncher.Builder()

                        .setMemberName("server1")
                        .setServerPort(40404)
                        .set("start-locator", "localhost[8091]")
            .build();
                serverLauncher.start();
                System.out.println(serverLauncher.status());
String restapi ="http://localhost:8091/gemfire-api/v1/";
             //   URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(restapi).openConnection();
                try {
                    URL obj = new URL(restapi);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    con.setRequestProperty("accept","application/json");
                    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println(responseCode);
                   // if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                con.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(inputLine);
                        }
                        in.close();

                        // print result
                        System.out.println("reason"+response.toString());
```

> Server in C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\Gemfire on DESKTOP-MRCV2EH[40404] as server1 is currently online.
>   Process ID: 2640
>   Uptime: 7 seconds
>   Geode Version: 9.5.1
>   Java Version: 1.8.0_171
>   Log File: C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\Gemfire\server1.log
>   JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.jmx-manager-bind-address=localhost -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=54053:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Getting response code : -1 , Invalid Http response.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your source code locally (plus one/two small modifications), and everything seems to work just fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Integer httpServicePort = 8080;
    ServerLauncher serverLauncher = 
        new ServerLauncher.Builder()
        .set("log-file", "")
        .set("http-service-port", httpServicePort.toString())   
        .set("start-dev-rest-api", "true")
        .set("http-service-bind-address", "localhost")
        .setPdxReadSerialized(true)
        .build();

    serverLauncher.start();
    System.out.println("REST server successfully started, press any key to stop it...");
    String restapi ="http://localhost:" + httpServicePort + "/gemfire-api/v1/";

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(restapi);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("accept","application/json");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

         if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
               String inputLine;
               StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
               while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   response.append(inputLine);
               }

               in.close();
               System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
         }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.in.read();
    serverLauncher.stop();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Running the above program prints the following:

```
REST server successfully started, press any key to stop it...
Response Code: 200
Response: {  "regions" : [ ]}
```

Did you correctly set the `GEODE_HOME` environment variable?, what about the `port` used when executing the `curl` command?, is the same number that you configured through the `http-service-port` property?.
Cheers.

Comment: Great!. I'd suggest to go through the [User Guide](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/gemfire/about_gemfire.html) from now on, the example I've attached is an exact copy of the instructions found in [Setup and Configuration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/setup_config.html).
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing the `GEODE_HOME` environment variable within your source code, which is needed by the server during the startup in order to find the libraries required to start the REST API, specifically `install-dir/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-n.n.n.war`. You can find more details about this in [Setup and Configuration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/setup_config.html).

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Http service started successfully done as you said, Still getting  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response

Comment: Hey Sarv, that doesn't seem like a GemFire error... have you tried the examples shipped with the product?. You can find them at [Sample REST Applications](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/rest_examples.html). Cheers.

Comment: I am not able to understand why the server is returning -1 as response code. @Juan Ramos

Comment: Have you followed the steps highlighted in [Setup and Configuration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/rest_apps/setup_config.html)?, what's the output of `curl -i http://localhost:selectedPort/geode/v1`?.

Comment: Failed to connect to port, Connection refused @Juan Ramos

Comment: https://community.pivotal.io/s/question/0D50e00005889rcCAA/unable-to-get-regions-list @Juan  Ramos Can you pls look into this